# d3.js Scatter Plot not zooming at the right scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a scatter plot with two different sets of axes. The first set of axes should be fixed to the left and bottom of the plot, scalable and zoomable (i.e., traditional plot axes). The second set of axes should be fixed to the plot, and go through the center of the graph.

When the graph zooms, the two sets of axes aren't scaling at the same rate, which means the outer axes don't accurately reflect the x/y of the plotted data.

I have a jsfiddle demonstrating what's currently happening http://jsfiddle.net/0kctabch/

---

EDIT: Removed the scale transform from the layer the inner axes are children of, as suggested by @mgold. Now, the inner axes aren't scaling at all on zoom. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0kctabch/1/

The code is below:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 25,
        left: 70
    };

var pointWidth = 2,
    defaultZoom = 1,
    maxWidth = 32768;

var palette = {
      "lightgray": "#819090",
      "gray": "#708284",
      "mediumgray": "#536870",
      "darkgray": "#475B62",

      "darkblue": "#0A2933",
      "darkerblue": "#042029",

      "paleryellow": "#FCF4DC",
      "paleyellow": "#EAE3CB",
      "yellow": "#A57706",

      "orange": "#BD3613",
      "red": "#D11C24",
      "harshRed": "#ff0000",
      "pink": "#C61C6F",
      "harshPink": "#ff6699",
      "purple": "#595AB7",
      "blue": "#2176C7",
      "green": "#259286",
      "yellowgreen": "#738A05"
}, colors = {
    selectedPoint: palette.darkerblue,
    background: palette.mediumgray,
};

//Create scales
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxWidth])
    .range([-1 * (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2)), (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2))]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxWidth])
    .range([-1 * (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2)), (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2))]);

var bottomScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxWidth])
    .range([-1 * (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2)), (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2))]);

var leftScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxWidth])
    .range([-1 * (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2)), (maxWidth * (pointWidth / 2))]);

// Create Axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .ticks(640)

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .ticks(640)
        .orient('left')

var bottomAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(bottomScale)
        .ticks(640)
        .tickSize(-height)

var leftAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(leftScale)
        .ticks(640)
        .tickSize(-width)
        .orient('left')

// Create map
var map = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
        .style('background', colors.background)
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

function createMap() {

    allPoints = map.append('g')
        .attr('id','allPoints');

    xGuide = allPoints.append('g')
    xAxis(xGuide)
    xGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2 + margin.left) + ', ' + (height/2) + ')')
        .selectAll('path')
            .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: '#000' })
    xGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: '#000' })

    yGuide = allPoints.append('g')
    yAxis(yGuide);
    yGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2 + margin.left) + ', ' + (height/2) + ')')
        .selectAll('path')
            .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: '#000' })
    yGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: '#000' })

    bottomGuide = map.append('g')
    bottomAxis(bottomGuide)
    bottomGuide.attr('class', 'x axis')
    bottomGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2 + margin.left) + ', ' + height + ')')
        .selectAll('path')
            .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: '#000' })
    bottomGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: '#000' })

    leftGuide = map.append('g')
    leftAxis(leftGuide);
    leftGuide.classed('y axis', true)
    leftGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height/2) + ')')
        .selectAll('path')
            .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: '#000' })
    leftGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: '#000' })

    applyZoom();
}

function applyZoom() {
    var setZoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scale(1)
        .scaleExtent([0, 10])
        .x(bottomScale)
        .y(leftScale)
        .on('zoom', zoom); 

    d3.select('#map svg').call(setZoom);
}

function zoom() {
    d3.select('#allPoints')
        // .attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate.join(',') + ')scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate.join(',') + ')');
    map.select('.x.axis').call(bottomAxis);
    map.select('.y.axis').call(leftAxis);
}
createMap();
```

Comment: Judging by the varying text size, the centered axes are children of an element with a scale transformation.  You should try to remove duplicate code and create a demo that is as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes, the hierarchy is:
-> svg
  -> g.allPoints with transform translate/scale
    -> center x axis
    -> center y axis
  -> bottom axis
  -> left axis

I'll try removing the scale transform and see how that affects things

Comment: Didn't realize how unhelpful that comment would be... hierarchy is:
 svg {g.allPoints {innerX, innerY}, outerX, outerY}. I removed the scale transform from g.allPoints, but now, as expected, that layer isn't scaling at all, let along to match the scale of the outer axes. I'll update the post with the current fiddle now.

Comment: I didn't say remove the scale. You should probably start with this example and add central axes: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919